# How to submit from either of two identical web forms?

Tags: javascript, forms, window.open

I have the following simple form used twice on the same page...

```
        <form>
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg mb-3 p-2 bg-warning rounded">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="My company name" aria-label="My company name" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" id="mycompany">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button" id="mybutton">Get started!</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

The following JavaScript grabs the text input and uses it to form a URL parameter for a URL we send the user to...

```
  <script>
    document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener(
      "click", function(){
        const inputValue = document.getElementById('mycompany').value;
        window.open("https://airtable.com/myformidgoeshere?prefill_Company=" + encodeURIComponent(inputValue));
      }
    )
  </script>
```

That much I have learned.
And it works, for the first form instance - but not the second.

The problem is, how do I ensure that *either* of the little forms can produce the same effect?

Do the id for the text input and button need to be unique?

And, either way, how can the same JavaScript function handle the window opening for *whichever* of the forms is submitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

---

1. [Option 1 Js Fiddle](https:////jsfiddle.net/lenny86/ksghe2bv/14/). Change the ID's so they become unique within the document *(example id="mybutton1", id="mybutton2" same for "mycompany")* and add the event listeners separately for each button. Define the callback function as a global function and call it on each button.

---

```
function newWindow(inputArea) { //pass input field ID as argument
    const inputValue = document.getElementById(inputArea).value;
    window.open("https://airtable.com/myformidgoeshere?prefill_Company=" + encodeURIComponent(inputValue));
}

document.getElementById('mybutton1').addEventListener('click', newWindow.bind(this, 'mycompany1', false));
document.getElementById('mybutton2').addEventListener('click', newWindow.bind(this, 'mycompany2', false));
```

---

2. [Option 2 Js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lenny86/84v9e1th). Replace ID's with classes and loop through the forms.

---

```
<form>
<div class="input-group input-group-lg mb-3 p-2 bg-warning rounded form">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="My company name" aria-label="My company name" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mybutton" type="button">Get started!</button>
    </div>
</div></form>
```

---

```
//get DOM elements and return an array
let form = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.form'));

//loop through each form
form.forEach(e => {
    function openWindow() {
        let inputField = e.querySelector('.form-control').value;
        window.open("https://airtable.com/myformidgoeshere?prefill_Company=" + encodeURIComponent(inputField));
    }
    e.querySelector('.mybutton').addEventListener("click", openWindow)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'd have to use a unique button id to capture each event.

Below I suggest another approach, using querySelctors to traverse the DOM.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('form') // loop each form
  .forEach(form => form.querySelector('#mybutton').addEventListener('click', (e) => { //add the vent to the corresponding form button
    const inputValue = form.querySelector('#mycompany').value
    window.open("https://airtable.com/myformidgoeshere?prefill_Company=" + encodeURIComponent(inputValue));
  }))
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="input-group input-group-lg mb-3 p-2 bg-warning rounded">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="My company name" aria-label="My company name" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" id="mycompany">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button" id="mybutton">Get started!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<form>
  <div class="input-group input-group-lg mb-3 p-2 bg-warning rounded">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="My company name" aria-label="My company name" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" id="mycompany">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button" id="mybutton">Get started!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working for the first instance because `getElementById` returns only a single instance of an element with the id you pass to it - and if you have multiple instances on the page it returns only the first instance.

As you suggested, you could make the ids unique, which is probably what I would do as a quick and easy solution.

You could instead use `getElementsByName` without changing your script or markup too much, but then you would also have to do some extra validation for when one of the forms did not have any input as well as if potentially both of them had input (like if someone typed in the text input of both forms).  Seems like making the ids unique would be easier and faster.

As far as getting multiple forms to perform the same action, probably the cleanest thing you could do is create a method that listens to the submit event of the forms on your page and uses `event.target.elements['elementName']` to get the specific inputs by name.  Something like this:

```
<form>
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg mb-3 p-2 bg-warning rounded">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="My company name" aria-label="My company name"
            aria-describedby="basic-addon2" name="mycompany">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" name="mybutton">Get started!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<form>
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg mb-3 p-2 bg-warning rounded">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="My company name" aria-label="My company name"
            aria-describedby="basic-addon2" name="mycompany">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" name="mybutton">Get started!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    document.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const inputValue = e.target.elements['mycompany'].value;
        window.open("https://airtable.com/myformidgoeshere?prefill_Company=" + encodeURIComponent(inputValue));
    }, false);
</script>
```